# remove_action in plugin file

Tags: filters, plugins

Im trying to use

```
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'woothemes_updater_notice' );
```

In a plugin to keep from editing the themes functions.php file however the code isnt being executed. Do i need to wrap this in something to get it to work from the plugin files?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you remove the action *after* the theme has added it. And use the same priority.

A rather safe way is using the same action you want to clean up:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'remove_woothemes_updater_notice', 0 );

function remove_woothemes_updater_notice()
{
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'woothemes_updater_notice' );
}
```

Comment: Your way isn't working, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer just after posting. If anyone is having the same issue i solved it with this.

```
// Remove WooCommerce updater plugin notice
function woothemes_updater_notice() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'woothemes_updater_notice' );}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'woothemes_updater_notice' );
```

Comment: I find it funny that you need to _add_ and action in order _remove_ another one.

Comment: Only way i could get it to work.